# Code First, difficulty mapping a simple composite key join table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Please Help, having kittens here trying to do something that should be simple. I've got the hang of 1-1 and 1-M, but this> I'm just wanting to implement the composite key, i.e. PremiseServiceSubscription is acting as a join table having 2 foreign keys plus its own primary key. I want to be able to type Premise.PremiseServiceSubscription to get collection of all services for that Premise. How should I represent that here and using Fluent API?

```
public class Premise
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PremiseServiceSubscription> PremiseServiceSubscriptions { get; set; } 


}

public class PremiseService
{
    public int PremiseServiceId { get; set; }
    public string PremiseServiceDescription {get; set;}


}

public class PremiseServiceSubscription
{
    public int PremiseServiceSubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int PremiseServiceId { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working now...

[Key]
        public int SupplyPointServiceSubscriptionId { get; set; }

```
    [Column("SupplyPointId")]
    public int SupplyPointId { get; set; }
    [Column("SupplyPointServiceId")]
    public int SupplyPointServiceId { get; set; }
    public  DateTime EffectiveDateTime { get; set; }
```

with this in fluent API

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplyPointServiceSubscription>()
            .HasKey(p => new { p.SupplyPointId, p.SupplyPointServiceId });
```